# Can search robots index internal corporate domains?

Tags: search-engines

I was surfing Google and by chance the corporate GitLab domain came up in the search results. I tried to access it, but it gave me a DNS error. That is, this gitlab is deployed on the company’s internal network and employees access it either via a corporate VPN or on the internal network. My question is how could a search robot index it? I have one option: at some point it was accidentally opened for public access, the robot indexed it, and then it was closed. Is this true or are there other options?

Comment: Yes, that could be the reason why (you can search how Google index works: https://support.google.com/programmable-search/answer/4513925)